# WordPress plugin changelog RSS

Tags: plugins, rss

Is there a way to access a WordPress plugin's changelog RSS feed?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the plugins [trac revision log](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/wiki/TracRevisionLog) rss feed by using the format:

`plugins.trac.wordpress/log/plugin_name?format=rss&limit=100&mode=stop_on_copy`

Example: [feed link for the jetpack plugin revision log](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/log/jetpack?format=rss&limit=100&mode=stop_on_copy).

The revision log rss feed will only contain direct links to changeset diffs for any file committed with changes.

Example [changeset link](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/451771/jetpack).

You can also access the feed link directly from the plugin page on WordPres.org:

[image]

Comment: Lone link is not a good answer. Broken lone link is even less so. Please improve. :) **edit** tyvm, reversed my vote